# CCProxy and access to Internet on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome, proxy

I have installed the CCProxy on my Windows 7. But after running and start it I still have access to the Internet.

(I have access to internet on this machine with ADSL modem - No LAN)

my NIC IP : 192.168.100.1

CCProxy>Options>Local IP Address : 192.168.100.1

Windows>Control Panel>Internet Options>Connections>LAN Settings>check Use a proxy server for your LAN : 192.168.100.1    Port:808

Browser : Chrome

After installed and configured the CCProxy does not have access to the Internet?